# MetroStyleManager changes content's theme but not the form's theme

Tags: c#, java-metro-framework

I have been searching everywhere and cannot find an solution.

I have a button in my MetroForm and on_click it does the following:

```
metroStyleManager.Theme = metroStyleManager.Theme == MetroThemeStyle.Light ? MetroThemeStyle.Dark : MetroThemeStyle.Light;
```

I also have a white image as the background and I have the property `AllowImageInvert` set to `True` but when I actually click the button it changes the theme of all contents in the form but not the theme of the actually form.

So I tried adding this line of code:

```
this.Theme = metroStyleManager.Theme;
```

but it always seems to be one behind.

So I click the button and the content's theme is `Dark` while the form theme is `Light`. Another click changes the content's theme to `Light` and the form theme changes to `Dark`. I have it set-up the same as the example project that works fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I once faced this problem. Never really bothered to look into it. I ended up manually setting the theme of the Form. Perhaps this is a bug? I guess there's something wrong with how I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after hours of trial and error I finally fixed it.

Hopefully this will help anyone else who has this issue.

I finally added this to the end of the code:

```
this.Refresh();
```

so the final code looks like this:

```
private void mtleSwitchTheme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    metroStyleManager.Theme = metroStyleManager.Theme == MetroThemeStyle.Light ? MetroThemeStyle.Dark : MetroThemeStyle.Light;
    this.Theme = metroStyleManager.Theme;
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: What it does is that it doesnt auto refresh like the normal GUI does in VS. Thats why you need "This.Refresh();"